# error C2099: initializer is not a constant at developer commend prompt VS 2017

Tags: c

```
void primeFinder (int start,int final);


int *prime_list=(int*)malloc(1*sizeof(int));
int element_number=0;

void primeFinder (int start,int final){
    /*if (start<1){
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }*/
    int i,j;
    for(i=start;i<=final;i++){
        for (j=start;j<=i;j++){
            if(i%j==0){
                break;
            }
        }
        if(i==j){
            element_number++;
            prime_list=(int*)realloc(prime_list,element_number*sizeof(int));
        }
    }
}
```

It gives the error given below. Is it about compiler? I'm using "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017"

```
error C2099: initializer is not a constant
```

Comment: Pleasse explain the purpose of this line `int *prime_list=(int*)malloc(1*sizeof(int));`

Comment: Program will create list of prime numbers in given range. I want to set array first because it will be reallocated. So it is for set up the array

Comment: Although it might be (more or less) obvious in this case, but when mentioning a compile time error along with more then one line of code, it makes sense to mention the line, provoking the error. This is not a guessing game, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to move allocation from the global pointer declaration

variables with the static storage (global) require constant initializers.

```
int *prime_list;

int main(void)
{
  prime_list = malloc(1*sizeof(int));
  .....
```

If you compile C program using VS you need to set the proper compile language:
[image]

After that you will compile it as a C program.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an attempt to in itialise `prime_list` in a way which only is possible with a constant.

```
int *prime_list=(int*)malloc(1*sizeof(int));
```

The use of malloc however is a call to a function, which can only be done at rune time and therefor has to be part of a function.

That is what the compiler is telling you.

If you want to initialise with a malloced (and very small) initial buffer, then you probably need something of an initialisation function, called beforehand.